# PostgreSQL remote access with existing user name

Tags: postgresql

I would like to access my PostgreSQL 8.3 database with the name of an existing user but, when I try, I get a password authentication failure.  I am able to access the database by creating a new Postgres user:

```
postgres createuser -P newusername
```

So I tried createuser with the existing user name but it said that that user already existed and wouldn't let me create it.

In pga_hba.conf, I have:

```
host   db_name   all   0.0.0.0/0  md5
```

and it doesn't complain about the connection - only the password authentication. Is there a way to remotely access the database using an existing user?

Answer (score 2):

try changing your pg_hba.conf to:

```
host db_name all 0.0.0.0/0 password
```

Note usage of **password** instead of **MD5**.

Also, if you are trying to connect from the same machine the DB is hosted at, then on you command line try:

```
$ psql -h IP_ADDRESS_OF_PG_SERVER -u USER -d DB_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks. It didn't make a difference. I'm using the same method for the one that doesn't work as the one that works anyway.  So I wouldn't expect md5 vs. password to make a difference.

I'm connecting from a remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Doh. The problem was I was using the wrong password.